# Why are ssh and git push not working?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, terminal, ssh, git

So recently, I have noticed that commands like `ssh`, `git push`, and `git pull` sometimes stop working. They only start working after I restart my computer. The interesting thing is that I can still browse the web, use other apps that require internet access perfectly fine.

I cannot SSH or make a VNC connection to a computer at my home, or pull/push on repos. Anybody have any idea what seems to be the issue? I am on **macOS Siera 10.12.5** on an **Apple MacBook Pro 2015**.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have a similar issue back in Yosemite. Here is how I fixed it:

**System Preferences** -> **Security or Security & Privacy.** -> **Firewall Tab** -> **Click the Lock and enter your password** -> **Toggle Firewall on and off** -> **Restart your computer**

Comment: Thanks so much, I actually managed to figure this out myself a little while ago